# Y capacitors in surge suppressor in a TN-C-S system

Tags: capacitor, emc

"Surge Protectors", "power strip", etc. I noticed many of them have Y caps (line-earth/neutral-earth) usually 102 or 222M Y safety caps to filter line and earth neutral and earth noise

are they redundant/non-issue in a TN-C-S system or do they cause any disturbance to the neutral mains?

Those Y caps are usually placed in the connector itself in 1 pair neutral and earth - line earth or in the pcb
Just an example this picture
http://hardwareinsights.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Input-filtering.jpg
Should I shop for a powerstrip/surge protector without Y caps in a TN-C-S system?

Comment: Why should they be redundant?

Comment: Those Y caps support the PSU CM choke filter for EMI however any residual will also conduct on N in TN-C-S

Comment: @Andyaka due to the fact the X2 cap is alread filtering Neutral and neutral and earth are combined in a TN-C-S system

Comment: Why would you shop for a thing without them fitted? It doesn't make any sense? Are you trying to save money (like a few pennies)?

Comment: @Andyaka I'm just curious if a TN-C-S system the Y cap in the surge protector is redundant since the X2 cap (line-neutral) is already filtering noise from the neutral side. In a TN-C-S system neutral is PEN (earth)

Comment: Do you actually have a reasonable and well researched question goin on? Only earth is earth wen it comes to EMC and lightning surges.